# Класс object в Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

Имеет ли смысл писать `class BasicHandler(object):` в Python 2? Разве `object` не наследуется по умолчанию ?

Comment: Во втором - имеет. Подробнее, например, [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374857/should-all-python-classes-extend-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во втором - имеет. Классы по умолчанию **не** "нового стиля" ("новые" классы были введены в 2002 году), но ради совместимости все оставили как есть. Новый класс или старый влияет не то что бы на очень многое, но будет отличаться вывод `type()`, порядок вызова методов при наследовании - [2.3 MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), метаклассы, способ вызова `__специальных__` методов. Перепечатывать все, наверное, не имеет смысла - можно подробнее почитать [здесь](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/)